# Need to write recursive date function in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I'm having one holiday table based on that I need to return last working date.

```
Table_holiday

Id Date        Text
1  2013-03-29  Good Friday
2  2013-05-01  Maharashtra day
3  2013-05-02  Holiday
```

When I execute my `date_recursive` function it should have to check and return me `last_business` date

`For example`

If I execute it on `@date datetime = '2013-03-29'` it should return me `last working date '2013-03-28'`as this is the last working date

any help m newbie in sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @Table_holiday as TABLE(id int, [date] datetime, [Text] nvarchar(50))
insert into @Table_holiday values(1, '2013-03-29', 'Good Friday')
insert into @Table_holiday values(2, '2013-05-01', 'Maharashtra day')
insert into @Table_holiday values(3, '2013-05-02', 'Holiday')

declare @date datetime
set @date ='2013-03-29'

;with T(dt) as
(
    select @date union all
    select T1.[date] from T inner join @Table_holiday T1 on T1.[date]=T.dt-1
)select min(dt)-1 from T
```

Comment: Please add a sample data for that.

Comment: If my function will only execute on weekday then above logic working fine for me :)

instead of #temp holiday table I'm adding permanent holiday table :)

Thanks techdo
Also please add code if there is anything missed out

Comment: please elaborate what is lwd ? i'm new to CTE please explain

Comment: @ashuthinks Sorry... No need of that... was a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming ANY date **not** in your holiday table is a working date, you can search backwards until you find a non-holiday.

```
;with cte(adate) as (
    select @date
    from table_holiday
    where @date = Date
    union all
    select h.Date
    from cte
    join table_holiday h on dateadd(d,-1,cte.adate) = h.Date
)
select isnull((select dateadd(d,-1,min(adate)) from cte), @date);
```

Comment: Thanks @RichardTheKiwi Can you please elaborate more how the above CTE date function is different from below ans given by techdo
I'm new to CTE please elaborate..

Comment: techdo's answer uses CTE as well, he named it "`T`". His answer is technically better and starts from the day AFTER the last working day you're after. I assumed @date is the last working day, but goes backwards if it's a holiday. `techdo` assumes you want a working day **before** @date.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select (case when DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),'2008-08-05')<2 Then "last
 working date" Else "" END) from Table_holiday
```

Hope its helpful.